# context.Request.Files returns null from jQueryFileUpload

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-file-upload, ashx

I am having to ditch uploadify in favour of jQueryFileUpload to accommodate non-Flash mobile users on a web app. However, my upload.ashx handler does not receive anything in the post from jQuery.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
            autoUpload: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: webroot + 'handlers/Upload.ashx',
            done: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                    $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
                });
            }
        });
```

The Handler code:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];
}
```

Why does `postedFile` return `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files.Get(0) as HttpPostedFile;
```

simples